# jQuery event fired twice on new element

Tags: jquery, html

I made a new element in a div with class "info", using html():

```
$(".info").html(
    $elementsString      // which places a bunch of form elements in there
);
```

And I fire an event on click:

```
$('.info').on('click', 'input', function(event){
    alert('ey');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But the event is fired twice. Anyone know why?

**JSFiddle**

Right, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5uHQz/1/)'s the JSFiddle.

Comment: Would you be able to post a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) example which shows your problem?

Comment: You're probably attaching the listener twice. Read though the code that calls `$('.info').on()`

Comment: Are you binding the event handler twice by any chance? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There are multiple input elements within your generated html code ?

Comment: I think you shoul call `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: are there 2 input in your loaded form ?

Comment: try to do: `$(".info").each(function() { alert('info'); })` to make sure there is one `info` class in your page.

Comment: There isn't enough information to reasonably answer this question at the moment.

Comment: There are several inputs in the div, more than two. It's only firing twice.

Comment: stopPropogation() worked. Thanks, gonna read up on that in docs.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can't nest inputs as they are self closing, and you can't click two at the same time. Same goes for `.info` elements, the click is triggered on inputs, so as long as the inputs doesn't have a `.info` class, you could have ten nesten `.info` elements as well.

Comment: `stopPropogation()` is a work-around not really getting to the source of the problem... if you post more context we should be able to fix the problem rather than cover it up.

Comment: If `stopPropagation` works with input elements, you probably have invalid markup.

Comment: @smerny Thanks, I'll post a jsfiddle then in a sec.

Comment: @adeneo not necessary, an .info element can contains an .info element which contains an input

Comment: @roasted - it can, but it won't fire a click handler twice if the handler is bound to the input.

Comment: @vanamerongen, it's nice you found the solution, but you should still post the context that shows the real problem in your question and then you can even answer your own question (by posting an answer).

Comment: @adeneo but OP is using delegation here, so event still propagate and fired click event: http://jsfiddle.net/DNq6e/

Comment: @roasted - ah, I see, like that! Good one, but it should be trivial to figure out a solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/DNq6e/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shoul call `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('.info').on('click', 'input', function(event) {
    alert('ey');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer so I can accept it in a few minutes.

Comment: so that means there is .info element nested inside .info element

Comment: Smerny is right ! You work-around the problem but don't get its origin.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Alright, I'll post a jsfiddle.

Comment: @downvoter you should consider to comment on downvote

Comment: I have added an additional answer that fixed the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If event.stopPropagation() doesn't work, you can compare the target and currentTarget in order to make sure you actually click on the correct element. Pretty much like this:

```
$('.info').on('click', 'input', function(event){
   if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Do stuff here...
   }
});
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Although `stopPropagation()` worked and I accepted it as an answer, the root of the problem was, in fact, caused bad mark-up. It was a bit of a jungle because of different scripts and PHP written through everything, but after cleaning everything up for the JSFiddle (inserted now at the bottom of the question) it became quite clear that I had nested `.info` elements.

**Bottom line:** had nested `.info` elements, so event was fired counting both of those. I solved this problem by changing the classname of one of those elements.